# Proving this sequence is monotonic and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm supposed to show that the following sequence is monotone (for $n\geq 2)$ and bounded:

$s_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(s_n+\frac{a}{s_n}\right),\quad s_1=a_0>0,\quad a>0$

I'm using induction for both parts. For showing it is monotone (I believe it is decreasing), I tried to do $s_3-s_2$ as the initial step and show that this number is negative, but what I got was $s_3-s_2=\frac{4a_0^2-(a_0^2+a)^2}{4a_0^3+4aa_0}$ and I'm not sure how to make sense of it... Do I know for a fact that $(a_0^2+a)^2$ is greater than $4a_0^2$? Only in that case will this look like it's decreasing...

As for showing that it's bounded, I believe it has a lower bound of $0$, and for the first step this is given. But when I want to use induction to show that this is true for the whole thing, I end up dividing by $0$... I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $s_n>0$. Then, for $n\ge 2$, $s_n=\frac{s_{n-1}+\frac{a}{s_{n-1}}}{2}\ge\sqrt{s_{n-1}\frac{a}{s_{n-1}}}=\sqrt{a}$, so $\{s_n\}$ is bounded below. Moreover, $s_n^2\ge a$ for $n\ge 2$.

Therefore, $2s_{n+1}=s_n+\frac{a}{s_n}\le s_n+\frac{s_n^2}{s_n}=2s_n$. Thus, for $n\ge 2$, $\{s_n\}$ is decreasing.

Comment: I'm not understanding the first line. How do we know $s_n>0$? Then, where does $\sqrt{s_{n-1}\frac{a}{s_{n-1}}}$ come from?

Comment: That $s_n>0$ is almost clear, cause $a_0,a>0$. If you don't believe that $s_n>0$, it is easy to show by induction. The inequality I'm using is known as Arithmetic-Geometric Inequality, and it uses the fact $s_n>0$.

Comment: Would the limit be zero?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Indeed, since $s_n\ge\sqrt{a}>0$, then $\lim s_n\ge\sqrt{a}>0$. Moreover, the limit is $\sqrt{a}$.